# Set a bundle start level programatically on embedded Apache Felix 5

Tags: osgi, bundle

I have embedded Apache Felix 5.0.0 in an application I'm building.

When installing the bundles to the Felix framework object, I have no way of setting the bundles start level from code, and I read everywhere that people do it by hand using Gogo, but because I'm going to automatically install and start the bundles, I'd like to be able to set the start level from my code.

How can I do that? I've read about some StartLevel class and such, but I have found no actual working code that shows how to use it to set the bundle start level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have a Framework instance if you use embedded Felix. In this case I think the following could work:

```
Bundle bundle = framework.getBundleContext().installBundle(location);
BundleStartLevel bundleStartLevel = bundle.adapt(BundleStartLevel.class);
bundleStartLevel.setStartLevel(xxx);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it's a pity that Felix's documentation is so bad that I couldn't find something like this that I think should be pretty common. But it's just like any OSGi documentation, completely lacking, and the books are really dated.

Comment: I suggest that you should check the OSGi core specification. After you made a sample application based on some tutorial, I think it is not that hard to read.